# Comparision between pointer and integer error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, string> opposites;
    opposites["A"] = "T";
    opposites["T"] = "A";
    opposites["C"] = "G";
    opposites["G"] = "C";
    string line = "AGATTATATAATGATAGGATTTAGATTGACCCGTCATGCAAGTCCATGCATGACAGC";
    int promoter_index,i;
    for (i = 0; i < line.length();i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == "T" && line[i+1] == "A" && line[i+2] == "T" && line[i+3] == "A" && line[i+4] == "A" && line[i+5] == "T")
            promoter_index = i;
    }
    int start_of_sequence = promoter_index + 10;
    cout << promoter_index;

}
```

I am trting to find TATAAT in "line", but when i try to compare it says "ISO C++ forbids comparision between a pointer and integer". Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string::operator[]` returns a character, not a c-string.

```
if (line[i] == "T" && line[i+1] == "A"...
```

should be

```
if (line[i] == 'T' && line[i+1] == 'A'...
```

The single-quote denotes a character, whereas the double-quote denotes a c-string.

c-strings are of type `const char[]`, which is implicitly converted to a `const char*`. `char`s are integral types in c++, so what the compiler is telling you is that you can't compare a pointer (the c-string "T") to an integral type (the `char` returned by the `operator[]`). The reason that the you're being told that you can't do that comparison in ISO C++ is that in the dark, brutal days of pre-standardization C++, you could do things like compare integral types and pointers for equality.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `std::string::operator[]` returns a reference to a `char`, whereas a string literal such as "T" is a `const char[N]`, which decays to `const char*` in the comparison. If you want to compare an element of `line` to a single character, use single quotes:

```
if (line[i] == 'T' && line[i+1] == 'A' ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You are erroneously attempting to compare individual *characters* to entire *strings*.

Using the subscript (`[]`) operator on a string gives you a single character, but `"T"` is a *string* literal. *(Yes, even though it only has one character.<sup>†</sup>)*

```
line[i] == "T"
/*****/   /***/
//  ^       ^
//  |       |
// char     |
//     char const[2]
```

Character literals are delimited by *single*-quotes, so you meant to write:

```
line[i] == 'T'
```

So, in context:

```
if (line[i]   == 'T'
 && line[i+1] == 'A'
 && line[i+2] == 'T'
 && line[i+3] == 'A'
 && line[i+4] == 'A'
 && line[i+5] == 'T')
```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> *Actually*, it also has a second character which you can't see — the *null terminator*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To get your program to compile just change the the literals to `''`.  For example `line[i] == 'T'`

Alternatively you can use `strcmp(&line[i], "T") != 1`, to compare if the values of two characters are equal.